# How to decode a multidimensional json array in lararvel with 'foreach' for specific values?

Tags: php, json, laravel, multidimensional-array, foreach

I tried to figure out in php how to receive specific values from a json file with the 'foreach' but so far I didn't got what I wanted to. I marked each of the lines with '//!' that indicates what I want to echoing out with the 'foreach'.

My main goal with this to use it in Laravel, after I got the logic with pure php. So maybe you know a better solution before the process.

So I would like to receive the datas likes this:
(just the data and not more)

(This section below will not change or extend, just to keep it mind the loop)

- Meeting information
- 1
- 2017-05-11 18:59:13
- 2017-05-11 19:03:39
- 2016-01-30 13:30:00
- Test Meeting 2
- Test

(This and further sections below (or upcoming) will change and extend)

- 20
- subject_02@test.com
- 2017-05-19 17:40:25
- 2017-05-19 17:40:25

(So this section gonna be a redundant with different datas as you can see)

- 21
- subject_03@test.com
- 2017-05-19 20:11:18
- 2017-05-19 20:11:18

  {
    "msg": "Meeting information",
    "meeting": {
      "id": 1,
      "created_at": "2017-05-11 18:59:13",
      "updated_at": "2017-05-11 19:03:39",
      "time": "2016-01-30 13:30:00",
      "title": "Test Meeting 2",
      "description": "Test",
      "view_meetings": {
        "href": "api/v1/meeting",
        "method": "GET"
      },
      "users": [
        {
          "id": 20,
          "name": "Subject_02",
          "email": "subject_02@test.com",
          "created_at": "2017-05-19 17:40:25",
          "updated_at": "2017-05-19 17:40:25",
          "pivot": {
            "meeting_id": 1,
            "user_id": 20
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 21,
          "name": "Subject_03",
          "email": "subject_03@test.com",
          "created_at": "2017-05-19 20:11:18",
          "updated_at": "2017-05-19 20:11:18",
          "pivot": {
            "meeting_id": 1,
            "user_id": 21
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }

PHP Code

```
<?php 
$data = file_get_contents("/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/meeting.json");
$json = json_decode($data  = file_get_contents("/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/meeting.json"), true);
// $push = var_dump($json);

// echo print_r($json, true) . "<br>" . "<br>";

echo "Static paths:" . "<br>" . "<br>";

echo ' => ' . $json . "<br>";

echo '[msg] => ' . $json[msg] . "<br>" . "<br>";//!

echo '[meeting] => ' . $json[meeting] . "<br>";
echo ' - [id] => ' . $json[meeting][id] . "<br>";//!
echo ' - [created_at] => ' . $json[meeting][created_at] . "<br>";//!
echo ' - [updated_at] => ' . $json[meeting][updated_at] . "<br>";//!
echo ' - [time] => ' . $json[meeting][time] . "<br>";//!
echo ' - [title] => ' . $json[meeting][title] . "<br>";//!
echo ' - [description] => ' . $json[meeting][description] . "<br>" . "<br>";//!

echo ' - [view_meetings] => ' . $json[meeting][view_meetings] . "<br>";
echo ' - - [view_meetings] => ' . $json[meeting][view_meetings][href] . "<br>";
echo ' - - [view_meetings] => ' . $json[meeting][view_meetings][method] . "<br>" . "<br>";

echo ' - [users] => ' . $json[meeting][users] . "<br>" . "<br>";

echo ' - [0] => ' . $json[meeting][users][0] . "<br>";
echo ' - - [id] => ' . $json[meeting][users][0][id] . "<br>";//!
echo ' - - [email] => ' . $json[meeting][users][0][email] . "<br>";//!
echo ' - - [created_at] => ' . $json[meeting][users][0][created_at] . "<br>";//!
echo ' - - [updated_at] => ' . $json[meeting][users][0][updated_at] . "<br>" . "<br>";//!

echo ' - - [pivot] => ' . $json[meeting][users][0][pivot] . "<br>";
echo ' - - - [meeting_id] => ' . $json[meeting][users][0][pivot][meeting_id] . "<br>";
echo ' - - - [user_id] => ' . $json[meeting][users][0][pivot][user_id] . "<br>" . "<br>";

echo ' - [1] => ' . $json[meeting][users][1] . "<br>";
echo ' - - [id] => ' . $json[meeting][users][1][id] . "<br>";//!
echo ' - - [email] => ' . $json[meeting][users][1][email] . "<br>";//!
echo ' - - [created_at] => ' . $json[meeting][users][1][created_at] . "<br>";//!
echo ' - - [updated_at] => ' . $json[meeting][users][1][updated_at] . "<br>" . "<br>";//!

echo ' - - [pivot] => ' . $json[meeting][users][1][pivot] . "<br>";
echo ' - - - [meeting_id] => ' . $json[meeting][users][1][pivot][meeting_id] . "<br>";
echo ' - - - [user_id] => ' . $json[meeting][users][1][pivot][user_id] . "<br>" . "<br>" . "<br>";

echo "Dynamic paths:" . "<br>" . "<br>";


foreach ($json as $key) {

    echo $key[users][0][id] . "<br>";
    echo $key[users][0][email] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Can you just add to your question on how you want the json data to be displayed as an end result. It'll be easier to analyse than going through the those large number of echo statements.

Comment: Sure I can. I'll describe anything, I really would like to solve this, so feel free to ask and I'll answer as soon as I can. And thank you!

Comment: Just for curiousness. Why don't you use `dd($json);` instead of the whole echo monolith?

Comment: @r4nd3l8888 i've added my answer. I assume you want this to be displayed in the frontend. I've written the code as per my understanding of your requirement. You can make the additional small changes that you need based on this.

Comment: Yea.... i really think you should be using 1) Laravel's relationships, 2) why youre using json files as storage I have no idea 3) you could use transformers to get the json you want 4) you have redundant & repeating code under your pivot.... why .... i have no idea. If you want I can write something for sticking the landing

Comment: Yes, you right. This json files stuff is just new for me. I try to understand the methods. How is working, where to put things and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i did it the laravel way since your going to port it to laravel anyway. Here's the complete code to get you started.

Add this to web.php route file

```
Route::get('meeting', 'MeetingController@index');
```

MeetingController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class MeetingController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $fileContent = file_get_contents("/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/meeting.json");

        $data = json_decode($fileContent);

        return view('meeting')->with(compact('data'));
    }
}
```

meeting.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>{{ $data->msg }}</li>
            <li>{{ $data->meeting->id }}</li>
            <li>{{ $data->meeting->created_at }}</li>
            <li>{{ $data->meeting->updated_at }}</li>
            <li>{{ $data->meeting->time }}</li>
            <li>{{ $data->meeting->title }}</li>
            <li>{{ $data->meeting->description }}</li>
            <br>
            @foreach($data->meeting->users as $user)
            <ul>
                <li>{{ $user->id }}</li>
                <li>{{ $user->email }}</li>
                <li>{{ $user->created_at }}</li>
                <li>{{ $user->updated_at }}</li>
            </ul>
            <br>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Afternoon I'll try out, sadly I have to work for now :/ 
It looks good by the way! I can't wait to see :D

Comment: Well I learned something. But I still need some help to mate it right. I'm a kinda newbie about this part, so my apologies. 
These are my settings according to your shared comment.
How should I wire the things? I would very appreciate if you could describe the method.
[link](http://matemolnar.dk/images/web.php.png) - web.php
[link](http://matemolnar.dk/images/MeetingController.png) - MeetingController.php
[link](http://matemolnar.dk/images/ind_meeting.blade.png) - ind_meeting.blade.php

Comment: @r4nd3l8888 i'm not able to understand what you're trying to say or ask. Could you be more clear and specific?

Comment: Sure. So, the thing is the system now is based on an API. Which is generate the json file. But my part is the view to receive those datas from this particular (generated) json file. I need to show those lines on the screen, but sadly it's not clear for me how to connect the things together to make it works. From 'MeetingController' through the 'web' to the 'ind_meeting.blade'.

Comment: @r4nd3l8888 i thought u wanted to get this done in laravel ultimately, so i assumed you would at least know the basic with laravel. I even gave you the most basic code to copy paste into your project to get it working. I would suggest you read the docs about the basics of `routing`, `controller` and `blade templates` https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/

Comment: I'm still learning this framework. Thank you the advice and the comments so far! :)